# c++ towupper() doesn't convert certain characters

Tags: c++, c++builder, unicode-string

I use Borland C++ Builder 2009 and my application is translated into several languages, including Polish.

For a small piece of functionality I use towuppper() to capitalize a string, to put emphasis on it when first ignored by the user.

The original string is loaded from a language dll, into a utf16 wstring object and I convert like this:

```
int length = mystring.length() ;
for (int x = 0 ; x < length ; x++)
    {
    mystring[x] = towupper(mystring[x]);
    }
```

All this works well, except for Polish, where following sentence: "Rozumiem ryzykowność wykonania tej operacji" converts to "ROZUMIEM RYZYKOWNO**ść** WYKONANIA TEJ OPERACJI" instead of "ROZUMIEM RYZYKOWNO**ŚĆ** WYKONANIA TEJ OPERACJI"

(notice that  the two last characters of the word "ryzykowność" do not convert).

It's not as if there are no capitalized Unicode variants of this character available.  Unicode character 346 does the trick.  http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/015a/index.htm

Is this a matter of an outdated library in my outdated compiler installation or am I missing something else ?

Comment: Are those characters normalized, or do they consist of multiple combined code units?

Comment: It should not be an outdated library, as both `ś` and `Ś` were present from Unicode v.1.1, dated 1993. If it is, it's an error of the creator of this function.

Comment: What is your C locale set to?  "Uppercase version of ch or unmodified ch if no uppercase version is listed in the current C locale. "  Are you in the unicode locale?  `std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");`?  From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/towupper some easy to read docs on the function found via google.  If this does not solve it, provide a [mcve]

Comment: Why one would use Borland nowadays ?

Comment: @nikau6: well, why not? CBuilder has its own version of interfacing with Windows, but for the rest it's just another C++ IDE.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Implementations of `towupper` are not required by the C++ standard to perform Unicode case conversions. Even if wide strings are Unicode strings. Even in cases where one lower-case codepoint mapps to one upper-case one.

Furthermore, `towupper` is incapable of performing proper Unicode case conversion, even if the implementation supported it. Case conversion can actually change the number of codepoints in a Unicode character sequence. And `towupper` is incapable of doing that.

You *cannot* rely on the C++ standard library for dealing with Unicode matters of this sort. You'll need to move to a dedicated Unicode library like ICU.

Comment: A good implementation of the standard library would still be able to perform case conversion where the number of codepoints didn't change though.

Comment: @M.M: Even if an implementation provides wide character functions that try to implement Unicode as much as possible, it is still a promise that cannot be kept. Unreliable functions are *unreliable*. If you need Unicode to work, then you need it to *actually work*, not mostly work except for when it doesn't.

Comment: @NicolBolas it all depends on the problem domain. If you know that you will be working with a limited subset of all possible languages, it would be useful to know if a simple approach would or would not work for those specific languages.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Problem domains change. It's a hard jump from English to Spanish/French; you need to break out of ASCII encoding. But it's just as hard of a jump from English to *Unicode*, assuming you have access to a Unicode-capable library. Jumping from limited post-ASCII to Unicode requires lots of work too (for example, case-conversion can no longer be character-to-character, but string-to-string). Better to do all of the work correctly the first time, so that when your boss says you need German support (where `towupper` fails), you can just have it, rather than having to break the world.

Comment: @NicolBolas I undertand what you're saying and this would indeed make this approach unsafe, but unless I'm wrong, in this situation both cases are well within the 2 byte range, just one codepoint for both characters.  So, still strange ?

Comment: @Peter: Implementations are not required to perform Unicode case conversions, even with `towupper`, even in 1:1 mapping cases, even in cases where the implementation expects wide-strings to actually be Unicode-encoded. As such, `towupper` is not a reliable method for performing case conversion.

Comment: If a third party library is the only way, what would you suggest that works well with Borland C++ Builder 2009 ?

Comment: @Peter: The only Unicode library I know of is ICU, and I have no idea if it works with a compiler from 2009. I imagine you could probably coax some older versions into it.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the real-world example of German, I forgot about ß→SS. It really does illustrate how complex the problem gets very quickly.

Comment: I figured, why not rely on Windows to do it for me, so I just tried `CharUpperW` ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647474(v=vs.85).aspx ) but the result is exactly the same ?

Comment: @Peter: it is possible your `towupper` just wraps `CharUpperW`, I found an implementation online which did exactly that. But you can download the latest codepoint breakdown from unicode.org and either make a simple 1-to-1 mapping set for only the codes you need, or (minding Nicol's comment on cases such as the German `ß`) a longer and more versatile function. (Bearing in mind that `ß` > `SS` is not a problem but the other way around *is*.)

Comment: @RadLexus I was indeed thinking of doing exactly that, as a dirty workaround until I can implement it properly.  I only use the uppercase code for a small piece of the functionality currently so ...

Comment: @RadLexus ß→SS is a problem when you use a function that can only return one character. SS→ß is an even *bigger* problem, unless culturally SS→ss is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows this will work :
EDIT Just realised you're using Borland, not Msvc.

```
 #include <cctype>
 #include <clocale>

 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "polish");

    wchar_t c[2] = { L'ś', L'ć'};
    wchar_t c1 = _towupper_l(c[0], _get_current_locale());
    wchar_t c2 = _towupper_l(c[1], _get_current_locale());

    return 0:
}
```

You first need to set the locale to 'polish' by using [setlocale](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwiEufr73LPRAhUFWhQKHf2RC3sQFggkMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Ffr-fr%2Flibrary%2Fx99tb11d.aspx&usg=AFQjCNF1OkIRsqdRQx8wCI6Ze3RF69ewHQ&sig2=mNneYGo39z5V3-8FVFWa5w). And then use [_towupper_l](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/45119yx3.aspx). 
Here's a [link](http://xoax.net/cpp/ref/cstd/incl/clocale/fn/setlocale/) that tells you what strings, referring to a specific language, can be used with `setlocale`.

EDIT :
Note that if I print the results :

```
_wprintf_l(L" c1 = %c, c2 = %c\n", _get_current_locale(),  c1, c2);
```

The output will be :

```
c1 = S, c2 = C
```

But if I watch the values of C1 and C2 in my debugger, I can see the correct results, with the accents. My console will just not print that kind of characters.

Comment: I don't necessarily know the locale of every sentence that may be passed to the routine and it could even be multiple languages in one sentence.  It also defeats the use of Unicode to start with.

Comment: @Peter What you have to understand is that, for example, in French, the uppercase of `é` is `E`, not `É`. But for other languages using the letter `é`, the uppercase of `é` is `É`, not `E`. So I don't know if what you ask is even possible, cause the uppercase of one letter is very language specific. EDIT : In my post there's a link about what strings can be passed to `setlocale`.

Comment: I see your point.  Thanks.  I think the ideal solution then is to ask my translators to provide two strings.  A lowercase string and an uppercase string